# How to implement hierarchy or recursive CTE in SAP HANA 1.2v

Tags: sql, hana, recursive-query

Im working on SAP HANA 1.2v.
I have a db table containing employee id and manager id.
Now i need to find circular references or internal looping within table between employee and managers.for instance 
A manager is B
B manager is C
C manager is A
In above example you can  see there is a loop i need to eliminate this.
But i see recursive cte is not possible in sap hana and also hierarchy function is allowed only from hana 2.0.
Can some one please help me how to solve this..
Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post your table structure / code / etc?

Comment: using cursors i am trying to loop over the result set. I thought of it is not a way to do.  Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

With HANA 1 there is no officially documented way to implement proper hierarchy processing. 
There exists the option to create a calculation view of type "hierarchy" but this has not been made externally available.

One option could be to look into your scenario and see if there might be constraints that allow for different approaches. E.g. if the maximum depth of the org-structure is known to be, say, 6, you could create a view that simply joins the table five times to itself and that returns columns with matches for each join/hierarchy level.

Comment: Would AMDP help?